# Does anyone have a real solution to the "Unfortunately ______ service has stopped?"

Tags: samsung, system-error

I have had a Samsung Note 3 going on 2 years. I love it but this problem is driving me crazy. This has been a problem for at least the past year. I know others that have the problem as well and I have yet to find a real solution.

It usually comes in the form of "Unfortunately Google Play has stopped," but since the update to Lollipop/Android 5.0, it has been Kindle. I hardly ever use the Kindle app.

I have tried everything and searched numerous online forums, etc. Nothing works.
Including the "Clear your cache, settings, etc," and battery removal.
These solutions do not work.

Does anyone know if anything different I can try? It is getting really annoying. Happens on Samsung Galaxy Note Tablet as well. Both unrooted. I'm hoping there's something I'm overlooking.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! There can be many reasons for a {service has stopped} error. You can actually use [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) to view device logs. This will help you better understand what's actually going on with your device.

It is difficult to pin-point an issue like that with Android because of its very nature. We can all have the same devices but have completely different experiences on them, based on configuration, how we use them, etc. Hopefully that will give you a better understanding of what's going on with your device. aLogCat doesn't work for your needs, try A[ndroid Remote Stacktrace.](https://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/)